# dojox horizontalrangeslider read value for definition expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, range, esri

I am wanting to use the value of a range slider to set a definition expression on my data.

A VAR of the data is created with:

```
var POP_Total = new FeatureLayer("..../services/RPP_15/HEX_Confidence_Scores/MapServer/2", {
                  mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
                  outFields: ["*"],
                  opacity: 0.5,
              });
```

A definition expression is then applied:

```
POP_Total.setDefinitionExpression("POP_Total_Class >= 4 AND POP_Total_Class <= 5");
```

In the above case the returned values are hard coded to only display the values between 4 and 5.  I wish to problematically change the values of the 4 and 5 with the values used in the range slider.  The range slider is created with:

```
   var sliderRules = new dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels({
                  minimum: 1,
                  maximum: 8,
                  labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"],
                  labelStyle: "font-size:9px;color: #333",
                  style: "width:220px;height:30px;"
              }, "ruler");



              var rangeSlider = new dojox.form.HorizontalRangeSlider({
                  name: "rangeSlider",
                  value: [1, 8],
                  minimum: 1,
                  maximum: 8,
                  discreteValues: 8,
                  style: "width:220px;",
                  onChange: function (value) {
                      //alert('change occurred');
                  }
              }, "rangeSlider");
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted by Aamir Suleman on another thread:

```
onChange: function (value) {
    var min = value[0];
    var max = value[1];
    var expression = "POP_Total_Class >= " + min + " AND POP_Total_Class <= " + max;
    POP_Total.setDefinitionExpression(expression);
}
```